# Is it possible to create multi-page drawings in Google Drawings?

Tags: google-drawings

I've been through all of the controls, but I don't see anything that would allow creating a new page.  I have a group of related drawings that I'd like to put in a single package.

My current Plan B is to create a presentation in  Google Slides, but the drawing tools are pretty weak there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google drawings are "single page", like a canvas.

You can insert drawings in documents, sheets, slides, Google Sites pages and web pages.

**References**
[Paint and create charts and diagrams with Google Drawings - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/177123?hl=en)

Answer (score 8):

No, but there is a decent workaround - create a new spreadsheet instead of a new drawing.

You can then add multiple sheets & insert a new drawing on each sheet.
You won't have to leave the spreadsheet to create and edit the drawings and will have all your drawings in one document

Answer (score 8):

This thread is kinda old but I hope this helps:

1. Go to "View" > "Zoom" > "50%".
2. Once your drawing has resized, drag the bottom right corner to make
   the canvas bigger.

Comment: This is the smartest and most effective answer.

Comment: Wow, didn't even know we could do this, it's good workaround

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround, similar to @Richard's solution, is to open a new Google Doc and create a separate page for each drawing. I prefer this to the Sheets solution because the Doc can link to existing drawings and are also not bound in canvas size like Drawings inserted into Sheets are.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Jamboard instead as you can add frames - a bit like a horizontal PPT. When you save each Jamboard it has all the frames there - no need to save in another app.